# In Android, when fetching data in Async task, how do you refresh the GUI when data is received in Asynch task?

Tags: android

In Android, when fetching data in Async task, how do you refresh the GUI when data is received in Asynch task?

Answer (score 3):

There's an `onPostExecute()` method in the AsyncTask. That's where you can refresh GUI.